# I'm having problems with: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'voice')

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So, "I" am coding a discord bot using discord.js. I am new to java, but know a bit of python... I'm using slash commands with my bot and the error appears when I try to use a specific command(3 slash commands are somehow working).
Edit... Terminal error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'voice')
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\Uporabnik\Desktop\DiscBot\src\commands\Community\play.js:30:27)
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\Uporabnik\Desktop\DiscBot\src\events\interactionCreate.js:13:27)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Uporabnik\Desktop\DiscBot\src\functions\handelEvents.js:8:58)
    at Client.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\Uporabnik\Desktop\DiscBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:97:12)
    at module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (C:\Users\Uporabnik\Desktop\DiscBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\Uporabnik\Desktop\DiscBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:352:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\Uporabnik\Desktop\DiscBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:489:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\Uporabnik\Desktop\DiscBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:328:10)
    at callListener (C:\Users\Uporabnik\Desktop\DiscBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:290:14)
```

The bot does not crash.

Edit... So here's the code for the command "play":

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const { QueryType } = require("discord-player")

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("play")
        .setDescription("Plays songs from youtube")
        .addSubcommand((subcommand) =>
            subcommand
                .setName("song")
                .setDescription("plays a single song from a url")
                .addStringOption((option) => option.setName("url").setDescription("Paste the song's url").setRequired(true))
        )
        .addSubcommand((subcommand) =>
            subcommand
                .setName("playlist")
                .setDescription("Loads a playlist of songs from a url")
                .addStringOption((option) => option.setName("url").setDescription("Paste the playlist's url").setRequired(true))
        )
        .addSubcommand((subcommand) =>
            subcommand
                .setName("search")
                .setDescription("Searches for sogn based on provided keywords")
                .addStringOption((option) =>
                    option.setName("searchterms").setDescription("Type in the search keywords").setRequired(true)
                )
        ),
        async execute( client, interaction ) {
        if (!interaction.member.voice.channel) return interaction.editReply("You need to be in a voice channel to use this command")

        const queue = await client.player.createQueue(interaction.guild)
        if (!queue.connection) await queue.connect(interaction.member.voice.channel)

        let embed = new MessageEmbed()

        if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === "song") {
            let url = interaction.options.getString("url")
            const result = await client.player.search(url, {
                requestedBy: interaction.user,
                searchEngine: QueryType.YOUTUBE_VIDEO
            })
            if (result.tracks.length === 0)
                return interaction.editReply("No results")
            
            const song = result.tracks[0]
            await queue.addTrack(song)
            embed
                .setDescription(`**[${song.title}](${song.url})** has been added to the Queue`)
                .setThumbnail(song.thumbnail)
                .setFooter({ text: `Duration: ${song.duration}`})

        } else if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === "playlist") {
            let url = interaction.options.getString("url")
            const result = await client.player.search(url, {
                requestedBy: interaction.user,
                searchEngine: QueryType.YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST
            })

            if (result.tracks.length === 0)
                return interaction.editReply("No results")
            
            const playlist = result.playlist
            await queue.addTracks(result.tracks)
            embed
                .setDescription(`**${result.tracks.length} songs from [${playlist.title}](${playlist.url})** have been added to the Queue`)
                .setThumbnail(playlist.thumbnail)
        } else if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === "search") {
            let url = interaction.options.getString("searchterms")
            const result = await client.player.search(url, {
                requestedBy: interaction.user,
                searchEngine: QueryType.AUTO
            })

            if (result.tracks.length === 0)
                return interaction.editReply("No results")
            
            const song = result.tracks[0]
            await queue.addTrack(song)
            embed
                .setDescription(`**[${song.title}](${song.url})** has been added to the Queue`)
                .setThumbnail(song.thumbnail)
                .setFooter({ text: `Duration: ${song.duration}`})
        }
        if (!queue.playing) await queue.play()
        await interaction.editReply({
            embeds: [embed]
        })
    },
}
```

The code is not entirely mine, and I did change some things...
Hope someone understands my problem and thanks for reply.

Comment: looks like a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66372707/discord-js-typeerror-cannot-read-property-voice-of-undefined-can-someone-t

Comment: Please put all of your **code** and **errors** in **text** format. It is much harder for us to solve the problem without it in text. Please edit your question to include text. 

From what I can tell, it is line 30 that is the problem. `interaction.member.voice` is undefined. If you include some of your other code, we might be able to find out why.

Comment: Ok, I looked at the: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66372707/discord-js-typeerror-cannot-read-property-voice-of-undefined-can-someone-t and implemented the solution into the code. The solution fixed the undefined reading 'voice', but there is undefined reading 'member' now.